# Hi, line break text animation svg file

Tags: html, xml, svg

I'm working in a SVG animated banner and in the banner I have a typing text animation, everything goes well but I have a specific banner width, so I need keep typing effect in the second line and also the third line. How can I get a line break keeping the typing effect in the second and third line? WITHOUT USING JAVASCRIPT AND CSS

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg
width="600" 
height="700" 
version="1.1" 
viewBox="0 0 600 700" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
 <path id="path">
        <animate attributeName="d" from="m0,110 h0" to="m0,110 h1100" dur="2.8s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path> 
 <text 
 id="texto" 
 transform="scale(.71121 1.406)" 
 x="48.809311" 
 y="216.08093" 
 fill="#000000" 
 font-family="sans-serif" 
 font-size="17.42px" 
 image-rendering="auto" 
 stroke-width="2.4355" 
 style="line-height:1.25" 
 xml:space="preserve"
 >
 <textPath xlink:href="#path">
 <tspan x="48.809311" 
 y="216.08093" 
 stroke-width="2.4355">Este es el texto que estamos probando</tspan>
</textPath>
 </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got it right, but it looks like you'll need to use a `path` and `textPath` for each line. Hopefully someone more well versed with SVGs can chime in for an improved method.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg width="600" height="700" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 600 700" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <path id="path">
  <animate attributeName="d" begin="0s" from="m0,110 h0" to="m0,110 h1100" dur="2.8s"fill="freeze" repeatCount="0"/>
  </path>
  <path id="path2">
  <animate attributeName="d" begin="3s" from="m0,130 h0" to="m0,130 h1100" dur="2.8s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="0"/>
    </path> 
 <text 
 id="texto" 
 transform="scale(.71121 1.406)" 
 x="48.809311" 
 y="216.08093" 
 fill="#000000" 
 font-family="sans-serif" 
 font-size="17.42px" 
 image-rendering="auto" 
 stroke-width="2.4355" 
 style="line-height:1.25" 
 xml:space="preserve"
 >
 <textPath xlink:href="#path">
 <tspan stroke-width="2.4355">Este es el texto que estamos probando</tspan>
  
</textPath>
 <textPath xlink:href="#path2">
 <tspan stroke-width="2.4355">probando estamos que texto el es Este</tspan>
  
</textPath>
 </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a posibility:

Instead of 2 values for the animation (`from` and `to`) you can use several `values` for the animation and you can add a line break by adding a move to command `M` to the path. In the next example I've added a stroke to the path so that you can see it (helps with debugguing). you can delete the stroke attribute.

Also I've removed the x and y attributes of the text and tspan so that the text stands over the path. You can add those back if you need them.

```html
<svg width="600" height="700" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 600 700" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <path id="path" stroke="black">
    <animate attributeName="d" values="M0,110 h0;                           
                         M0,110 H230; 
                         M0,110 H230 M0,150 h0;
                         M0,110 H230 M0,150H230" dur="2.8s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
  <text id="texto" fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="17.42px" image-rendering="auto" stroke-width="2.4355" style="line-height:1.25">
    <textPath xlink:href="#path"><!--
      --><tspan stroke-width="2.4355">Este es el texto que estamos probando, y este otro también</tspan>
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```